# Fragment within Tab Activity losing all data when rotating?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

I am using the Sherlock ActionBar library and I have a SherlockFragmentActivity implementing ActionBar.TabListener (for my tabs) and I have 3 tabs...each being a SherlockFragment. When I rotate, the entire Activity is recreated and I lose all variables declared in my onCreate within the Fragment. How would I go about fixing this?

I figured I should be using fragments as tabs instead of activities...is this wrong?

**EDIT:** I should mention that my current workaround is to have static Lists in the Tab Activity and have the fragment push stuff to those lists on onPause (and get stuff back from them on onResume). I REALLY don't like doing this and I know there has to be a better way.

Also, regarding if(savedInstanceState==null), I've tried that and it doesn't seem to work. I think it's because the Activity that holds my Fragments is being recreated and the tabs need to be recreated.

Comment: Are you retaining the Fragments?

Comment: perhaps not? This is the first time I've used Fragments in an application.

Comment: There should be a method called setRetainInstance() or something like that. I'm on a very poor connection right now, so can't check it for you.

Comment: I have setRetainInstance(true); in my onCreate but onCreate is still called when rotating.

Comment: All right. I'd probably use the ViewPager instead of a tab listener. The ViewPager automatically stores the state of fragments.

Comment: Actually, your answer was right. If you want, put it in the answer and I'll select it. I needed your answer + the savedInstanceState check in the Activity class. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that's great! I've just added an answer to help others more easily :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a method called `setRetainInstance()` in the `Fragment` class, that you need to set to `true`. That'll save the instance of your fragments, and you can then check for any saved instances in `onCreate()`.

More info available here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: thanks. This is what I needed in addition to      if(savedInstanceState==null){
 //create tabs
}
within my onCreate() for the tab Activity

Comment: nice one, previously i was handling these stuff at onConfigurationChanged and re-creating all the fragments for new layout. Your solution might be more effective.

Comment: @GökhanBarışAker It should be, yes :-)